CC Avenue integration error: ASP.NET MVC 5
I  am trying to integrate CC Avenue in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I get an error on the landing page, however the same code is working fine for another web application.
No error code can be seen when it fails.
Any help will be appreciated.
This is a screenshot of the error for reference:


I reviewed my issue and figured out that I'm not sending the correct Payload as value of key, So Please Remove Special Char as=> (,), etc. from their value of Key.
Thanks.
